# How do you update an array within an array in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, document

```
user{
      '_id' : ObjectId(...),
      'Post' : [
                   {
                     'id' : ObjectId(...),
                      'Reply' : [
                                   '_id' : ObjectId(...),
                                   'Reply' : [
                                               ....*Repeated results*

                                             ]

                                ]
                    }                 

               ]

}
```

Im trying to have a recursive structure to my mongo database.  For example, replying to replies.  How would I access the structure I want, lets say the bottom structure. Post.Reply.$.Reply doesn't seem to work. (Replies also have other fields, like actual message, time, but I left them out for the example).

This is the query I've tried.

```
({
    'Post._id': ObjectId('512a48518f24a04b77946888'),
    '_id': ObjectId('5119cf32decedf8257ef6acf'), 
    'Post.Reply._id': ObjectId('512a49548f24a04b9b74ad6b')
}, {
    '$push': {
        'Wall.Reply.$.Reply': {
            'ParentId': ObjectId('512a49548f24a04b9b74ad6b'), 
            'UserId': ObjectId('511747a18f24a0069b7ed655'), 
            'Depth': 2, 
            'Time': datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 24, 14, 40, 52, 420056), 
            'Message': 'This post is not good!', 
            '_id': ObjectId('512a6cc48f24a04d189a1e3a')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: this is not a good structure to have - if you want to be querying and setting inner documents you won't be able to reach in not knowing the level of embedding in advance.